# Como deixar o exe gerado pelo electron-packager menor?

Tags: javascript, electron

[image: screenshot mostrando .exe com 82848KB]

Gostaria que meu executável do electron ficasse menor utilizo electron-packager, 
há alguma alternativa?

Comment: Deixando de usar o Electron? :) Agora sério, se você optou por usar algo de 2GB (provavelmente pra algo útil que faz pouca coisa), que importa um executável que não é 5% do tamanho total ser um pouco menor?

Comment: Bom eu sou novo electron, não exite maneira de deixar a aplicação menor ou com menos arquivo?

Comment: O que eu estou dizendo é que você está tentando resolver o problema errado, no momento que optou pelo Electron vai ter um trambolho pra administrar. A solução para o problema do tamanho é abandonar o Electron. Não entendo porque as pessoas estão adotando esta tecnologia porque ela tem problemas demais e entre eles o tamanho. Pelo menos seria coerente não reclamar disto. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXlxL.gif

Comment: Tentando dizer de outra forma: se você se preocupa com tamanho da aplicação e quantidade de dependências, definitivamente o Electron é uma tecnologia errada para se usar.

Answer (score -1):

Existem alguns procedimentos bem conhecido que podem ser utilizados para diminuir o tamanho do arquivo de um aplicativo Electron. E pode manualmente remover dependências desnecessárias e reduzir o tamanho do código fonte.

Duas ferramentas muito úteis para reduzir o tamanho do pacote são [**UglifyJS**](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) e [**Webpack**](https://webpack.js.org/). Ambas permitem minimizar e otimizar o código fonte.

Outra ferramenta bem conhecida é o [**UPX**](https://upx.github.io/) (Ultimate Packer for eXecutables), que é um utilitário de compactação de arquivos binários tanto para Windows como para Linux. possível compactar o arquivo executável do aplicativo, reduzindo significativamente

```
upx -9 myapp.exe
```

O [ASAR](https://github.com/electron/asar) é outra ferramenta que pode ser usada para empacotar os arquivos do aplicativo em um único arquivo, reduzindo o tamanho do pacote.

Por fim,  [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/) é uma ferramenta que combina várias técnicas de otimização, como compressão dos arquivos binários e exclusão de arquivos desnecessários.

Tanto o **UglifyJS** quanto o **Webpack**  , **asar** são instalados via npm

Comment: Eu dei +1, mas há um detalhe sobre o UPX: os anti-virus. É bem comum alguns anti-virus, em momento aleatorios, classificarem programas usando UPX como malware. https://github.com/upx/upx/issues/337 e https://github.com/upx/upx/issues/437. Além disso, dependendo do programa, isso acaba piorando, principalmente se o programa já é obfuscado. E, caso compartilhe o programa usando MSIX/APPX (...), ele já possui compactação, e o UPX acaba por se tornar (quase) inutil. _O mesmo ocorre com o APK (no Android), por exemplo, usar o UPX em um .so, dentro do APK é pior._

Answer (score -3):

É simples...

Você pode reduzir o tamanho do diretório **node_modules**

```
npm install modclean -g
```

```
modclean -n default:safe
```